# JSP{ - HTML Form - Submit Action - How to send to Java class for processing

Tags: java, html, jsp, forms

I have a JSP html based form. I want to do the post through my java code, i.e HttpURLConnection, OutputStreamWriter etc..

How do I make my form action process point towards my java class that is to do this post?

My aim is to have a:

1. JSP page that has a form,
2. Submit form
3. Processing and response called out my java code that will generate a response (this is working fine)
4. Response returned to the calling JSP page.

Really my issue is submitting the form, and send the processing to my java class?

Comment: Your java class, is it a servlet? And if not, do you have any special reason for using a java class that is not a servlet for doing your post.

Comment: the class isnt currently a servlet. I dont really know enough about them to implement it that way?

Comment: Do you know how to use `Servlet`?

Comment: no sorry I have not sured them before

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, here is an easy example on how to use servlet. What you actually need is a Servlet. A servlet is actually a java class. [Check this example](http://www.servletworld.com/servlet-tutorials/simple-servlet-example.html), replace `form.html` with your `jsp`  and let me know if you have issues. [This is a brief](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Servlet) description of what a servlet is.